# How to debug on console with Hapi.js Lab test framework?

Tags: node.js, testing, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

[Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) has the option to run tests with `mocha debug`, just like `node debug`, allowing debug within a `REPL` console.

How can I do `REPL` debug with [Hapi Lab](https://github.com/hapijs/lab)?

Comment: There may be a better way but I normally just do `node debug ./node_modules/.bin/lab`. You can still pass any flags you normally would to lab e.g. `-i 12 -v` or whatever.

Comment: I tried that and my scripts shows _chaged_ by Lab, and not as written. :/

Comment: Not sure what you mean there.

Comment: That was because I had coverage enabled. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just have to run `node debug node_modules/.bin/lab *.js`, just like @matt-harrison said.

The only tip is: *Do not use coverage when debugging*, since the coverage will change the original code and make debug difficult.